# accessing an object from a pop up window in parent window

Tags: textbox, popup

i have a pop up window in which there is a grid on rowselecting i have an object that is created that contains all the row elements. I want to assign these values to text boxes in the parent window can anybody please help me with this.

Regards
-Vishu

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly your question. because I don't know what language you are using. But, if you want using an object on popup window in parent window, you can set modifier of object in popup window is "public" and that object must be global variable. and you can use that object in parent window

example:

```
popupWindow{

       public object A;
}

parentWindow{
       popupWindow pWin = new popupWindow();
       // here, you can use object A in parent window
       pWin.A = ....
}
```

I hope it will help you.